# Logitech wireless mouse M325 won't turn on even after replacing batteries

Tags: mouse, battery, logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse

I have a Logitech M325 wireless mouse that recently died. Usually, after replacing the battery, there will be a yellow light indicating that it's on/working. But even after going through an entire AA battery pack, this light won't turn on and the mouse won't work. I even bought and used a brand new battery pack. Still won't turn on.

And yes, I made sure that the mouse itself is set to green / turn on, and the battery is put correctly.

Is my mouse completely hopeless or is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Reset to that Mouse (mice commonly do not have a reset function).

Go through the steps in the article below (some of which you have done) and if the steps do not work, then the mouse needs to be replaced.

In particular from the article:

> If the Unifying receiver is plugged into a USB hub, try plugging it directly into a USB port on your computer.

> Try moving the Unifying receiver to a USB port closer to the mouse.

https://www.computing.net/answers/hardware/why-wont-my-logitech-m325-mouse-work/95621.html